# Auditable Timestamps Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to fix my database but it's not working and I don't know why. The problem is coming from auditable class.

That's the database Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USER_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    USER_LOGIN VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ROLE_ID INT,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE NOT NULL,
    GENDER_ID INT,
    CITY_ID INT,
    COUNTRY_ID INT,
    IS_ENABLED BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    TIMESTAMP_CREATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CREATED_BY VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP_UPDATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (CITY_ID) REFERENCES CITIES(CITY_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRY_ID) REFERENCES COUNTRIES(COUNTRY_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GENDER_ID) REFERENCES GENDERS(GENDER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENCES USER_ROLES(ROLE_ID)
);
```

That's the auditable class:

```
package com.docconnect.docconnect.entity.commons;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", length = 200, nullable = false)
    protected U createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP_CREATED", nullable = false)
    protected Timestamp createDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY", length = 200, nullable = false)
    protected U lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP_UPDATED", nullable = false)
    protected Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

}
```

That's the Hibernate message:

Hibernate: alter table USERS modify column TIMESTAMP_CREATED  datetime(6) not null

Hibernate: alter table USERS modify column TIMESTAMP_UPDATED  datetime(6) not null

How do I fix that? Where is the problem coming from?

I've basically tried everything from columnDefinition settings to setting the Timestamp to Date and nothing seems to work for me.